# How to change width in flexbox element using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox

How to change a width of a flex element using javascript?
I have this code  (fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sdgz8nxa/24/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  .container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
  }
  .bl1 {
    border: 2px solid lime;
    height 100%;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .bl2 {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height 100%;
    flex: 1;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="bl1"></div>
  <div class="bl2"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  $( '.bl1' ).append( 'before ' + $( ".bl1" ).css( "width" ) );
  //here can't change 
  $( ".bl1" ).css( "width", "300px" );

  $( '.bl1' ).append( '<br>after ' + $( ".bl1" ).css( "width" ) );  
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in output width always the same 
this row doesn't work $( ".bl1" ).css( "width", "300px" );

How to change width using javascript in flexbox block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define like that

```
$(".bl1").css( "flex", "0 1 300px" );
```

when you wrote for `.bl1` and `.bl2` `flex: 1;` that mean

```
flex-grow: 1;  // should be equal to each other
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

now you can say

```
$(".bl1").css( "flex", "0 1 300px" );
```

that mean

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 300px;
```

and flex-basis mean the width of the box and you can make fullback with `width:300px` for older browsers

```js
  $('.bl1' ).append( 'before ' + $(".bl1" ).css("width") );
  //here can't change 
$(".bl1").css( "flex", "0 1 300px" );

  $('.bl1' ).append( '<br>after ' + $( ".bl1" ).css( "width" ) );
```

```css
.container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
  }
  .bl1 {
    border: 2px solid lime;
    height 100%;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .bl2 {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height 100%;
    flex: 1;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bl1"></div>
  <div class="bl2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using width you can use the 'flex' property to change its size. You can use decimals too.